# Android 4.0.3(ICS) WebView Graphic issues

Tags: android, webview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have a issue about Android WebView.

It's OK on Android version gingerbread.

But ICS is not OK.

I just tried change element using $.post.

after that, stop the screen and graphic was broken.

after touching the screen, screen changes OK.

how can I fix this issue?

plz help me.

I Just use simple JQuery code.

```
$.get("pages/somepage.html", function(data) {
var text = '<div>'+data+'</div>';
$('.content').html(text); });
```

I think this issue from difference between 2.3.3 and 4.0.3 webview.

I don't know what it is. I guess web engine or webkit something.

Comment: Can you give some examples of your code?

Comment: Have the same problem, Clickable area on android 4+ are wrong. anyone?